# Does there exist a $b$ such that the integral exists?

Tags: improper-integrals, hypergeometric-function

I came across the following integral while working on my thesis,

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{b-1} (1-x)^{z_1+1} dx
$$
where $z_1 \in \mathbb{C}$ and $z_1 = a - wi$ where $a > 0$. Does there exists a $b$ such that the above integral converges?

I was trying on wolfram alpha, and it mentions something about hypergeometric function, but I'm not familiar with the concept.

Comment: @DonAntonio here integral is between $0$ and $\infty$ not between $0$ and $1$

Comment: Yeah, I did that same mistake at first, thought it was beta function, then I realized that the boundary was wrong. @DonAntonio

Comment: @stity Good catch, thanks. Deleting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr**:  No.  For $a>0$, there is no such $b$.

First, as $x \rightarrow \infty$, your integrand is approaching $x^{b-1}x^{a+1-w\mathrm{i}} = x^{a+b-w\mathrm{i}}$.  By [comparison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test#For_integrals) and the [$p$-test](http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/improper/testconv/testconv.html), this cannot converge if $a+b \geq -1$, so convergence of your integral requires $a+b < -1$.

Second, for $x \rightarrow 0$, your integrand is approaching $x^{b-1}\cdot 1$.  By comparison and the $p$-test, this cannot converge if $b-1 \leq -1$, so convergence of your integral requires $b > 0$.

Third, for $x \rightarrow 1$, your integrand is approaching $1 \cdot (1-x)^{a+1-w\mathrm{i}}$.  As in the second case, this cannot converge if $a+1 \leq -1$, so convergence of your integral requires $a > -2$.

These constraints give a triangle in the $a,b$-plane, with vertices $(-2,0)$, $(-1,0)$, and $(-2,1)$.  As long as $(a,b)$ is a point in the interior of that triangle, your integral converges.

Your integral is related to the [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).  In fact, $\int_0^1$ of your integrand is a value of the Beta function.  Today, I'm too lazy to find the change of variable (some variant of $x \mapsto 1/x$ or $x \mapsto 1-1/x$) to turn the $\int_1^\infty$ integral into a value of Beta.

---

Since OP apparently wants a CAS to provide the integral and conditions ...  Mathematica 11.2 gives

```
Assuming[{Element[a|b|w, Reals]},
  FullSimplify[
    Integrate[
      x^(b-1)(1-x)^(a-wI+1), 
      {x,0,Infinity}, 
      GenerateConditions -> True
    ]
  ]
]

(* Result:  
ConditionalExpression[
  Gamma[2+a-Iw] (
    Gamma[b]/Gamma[2+a+b-Iw] + (-1)^(1+a-Iw)Gamma[-1-a-b+Iw]/Gamma[1-b]
  ),
  b > 0 && a > -2 && a+b < -1
]
*)
```

And these are the same conditions on $a$ and $b$ identified above.

Comment: I did a fatal error, the $b$ in $z_1 = a + bi$ is not the same $b$ as in $p^{b-1}$, I'm terribly sorry. Though I think I can work out the details from your answer

Comment: Yeah, I figured it didnt really mather, sorry for the mistake and thanks for the help. :)

Comment: @Olba12 : This doesn't change much (the real parts of the exponents control convergence).  Updated with this change.

Comment: I said in my question that we must have $a > 0$, On the other hand you say that $b > 0$ but then $a + b < -1$ can not be fufilled.

Comment: @Olba12 : I agree.  Your positivity constraint on $a$ prevents convergence of the integral.

Comment: $\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{b-1} (1-x)^{z_1+1} dx = \int_{0}^{1} x^{b-1} (1-x)^{z_1+1} dx + \int_{1}^{\infty} x^{b-1} (1-x)^{z_1+1} dx = \frac{ \Gamma (b +1) \Gamma (z+1)}{ \Gamma (b+z+2)}$ + $\frac {(-1)^z  \Gamma (z + 1)  \Gamma (-b - z - 1) }{\Gamma (-b)}\\$, so $a > -1$  $b+ a < -1$ $b > -1$. wolfram says

Comment: @Olba12 : What does Wolfram Alpha think $a$ is, since that symbol appears nowhere prior to the conditions.

Comment: It says e.g$\Re (z) > -1$ which I translated to $a > -1$.

Comment: @Olba12 : Your translation to $a$ appears to include an off-by-one error.  I've included the input and output of a similar computation in my answer.